# Creating trigger for using procedure to insert manipulated data when the base table of procedure is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I created a procedure which uses query that manipulates data and insert manipulated data from base table to summary table. I want to use the procedure for only inserting newly inserted data from base table to summary table.

```
Create procedure x
as 
begin
insert into summary_table(a, b, c, d ...... h)
-- query 
   .....
   .....
; END x;
```

What is the appropriate way to invoke the procedure for this operation? I am experienced in writing queries but I am inexperienced for using db programmatically and also creating triggers, jobs, schedules. Therefore my question is just conceptual. And I just want to know best practices with minimal coding example.

Comment: You want to create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger using the `FOR EACH ROW` flag.  You can find documentation on this for Oracle 10g here: [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm)

Comment: Best practice would be not to write a procedure, not to create a trigger, and not to create a job.  If you want a summary table, you'd want to use a materialized view https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views

Comment: @JustinCave thanks a lot for your answer. I just wanted to know best practice from experienced people. I can write code with documentation.  Appreciated.

Comment: Best practice, as I said, would be to ditch the procedure, the trigger, and the job and use a materialized view.  The article I linked to provides a number of examples.

Comment: It very well by that @JustinCave is correct that a materialized view is the best practice. Especially so  *all things being equal*, but are all things equal. If your organization typically handles this task creating triggers then your best practice would be creating a trigger.  Consistency being a highly sought organizational goal. That is one reason why there is really no such thing as `best practice` that applies in all cases, but a set of `best  practices`.